# Php toggle with a form: logic error?

Tags: php, forms, logic, toggle

I can't get my head around why this code doesn't keep toggling.
What should be changed?

```
print_r( $_POST );
$direction = isset( $_POST['direction'] ) ? $_POST['direction'] : 'DESC';
$opposite = $direction == 'DESC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
echo '
    <form method="POST" >
        <input type="submit" value="' . $opposite . ' " name="direction">
    </form>
';
```

Comment: thx a bunch Dave, of coarse that's it! (answer with the speed of light)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is:

```
<input type="submit" value="' . $opposite . ' " name="direction">
                                            ^^
```

Notice how you've got an extra space at the end of the value, `value="' . $opposite . ' "`

Try changing it to:

```
echo '
    <form method="POST" >
        <input type="submit" value="' . $opposite . '" name="direction">
    </form>
';
```

Comment: thx a bunch Dave, of coarse that's it! (answer with the speed of light)